# mapping network drive with smartcard non domain

Tags: c#, windows, certificate

I am attempting to be able to use a smart card to map a network drive from a computer that is not joined to the domain. Whenever I try to use net use with the smartcard switch, i get the following error

net USE ERROR
Error: 1263 the kerberos protocol encountered an error while validating the KDC certificate during smartcard login.

More information from Event log Error

"the KDC certificate for the domain controller does not contain the KDC extended key usage (EKU): 1.3.6.1.5.2.3.5: Error code 0xc0000320. The domain administrator will need to obtain a certificate with the KDC EKU for the domain controller to resolve.

CN=MYNAME + OID.X.X.XXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXX.X.X=XXXXXXXXXX.COMPANYNAME.1, OU=People, OU=COMPANYNAME, OU=ORGNAME, C=US

CN=MYNAME.LAST@company.com

CN=MYNAME + OID.X.X.XXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXX.X.X=XXXXXXXXXX.COMPANYNAME.1, OU=People, OU=COMPANYNAME, OU=ORGNAME, C=US

Questions:

Is is possible to actually authenticate and map a network drive using net use and not being joined to domain? I know we have a cert we use to allow us to add computers to the domain with our smart cards, but doesn't work for this. Is the issue that net use isn't looking at right cert?  One more thing to mention is,  I have no way to modify or add certs to my smartcard. Please forgive my ignorance with this, first time messing with smartcards and certs.

If it is not possible, should I approach it with code instead? So far I have been only able to read the certs.

Comment: Please provide the code of your command. If you're authenticating on remote computer that is not in your domain, then you may need local user from that computer. Do that computer requires smart-card authentication?

Comment: @Mikhail Tumashenko

I am doing runas /netonly /user:COMPANY\domainuser /smartcard "cmd /k net use z:\"  .Whenever i do net use by it's self, I get error about "no logon servers are available". I attempted to set LOGONSERVER variable to my domain controller also. The local computer I am using does not require smartcard login, the server does require smart card.

Comment: Also I should mention that it does run cmd when I do runas. It doesn't give the the error until the second part of command involving the actual connection to server.

Comment: So, your domain user has sufficient rights on share from non domain machine? Have you tried to run `net use z:\` interactively?

Comment: that is correct, I can map to my server from my non domain computer with password just fine, just doesn't work when I try to use smart card to map. We are about to switch to smart cards only within a few days.

Comment: Have you added your domain Root certificate to Trusted on non domain machine? Non domain machine need an encrypted channel to authenticate user. So it must trust your domain controller and have it's certificate in Trusted Root.

Comment: I notice that when I do net use z: \\servername /user:UID@company.com it ask for PIN number, if I do anything else it just fails with cancelled by user.

Comment: I believe I did add it. The cert shows Subject =DC,COMPANY,NET

I see the cert under Trusted Root Certificates Authorities
should it be under smart card trusted root instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91492/discussion-between-user2190928-and-mikhail-tumashenko).